# Render 2 templates at the same time on Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I come from the `PHP` scenario, so this may be a wrong question.
I serve a page (templates with `Handlebars`) to client this way:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});
```

and it works, but what if **I need to divide my template in some different parts** (so I'm able to reuse one of this in many different way)? For example, I have a template for header and one for footer.

Something like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('header');
  res.render('content');
  res.render('footer');
});
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using handlebars template rendering service, you can use partials.

http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html

Code example: https://github.com/donpark/hbs/blob/master/examples/partial/views/index.hbs

The basic high level call stack follows like this:

```
res.render('page') ---> parses N of partials (recursively) --> html out
```